# Chrome Extension: accessing the length of an array that stores objects

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to access the length of an `array` that stores `objects`. When I print the `array` to the console, it just displays `1` when there is one `object` inside the array and displays `undefined` when I try to access the length of the `array`.

In my popup I have a text field that, once text has been entered and the enter key has been pressed, it will store all information from the tabs in the current window into `storage`. The information is stored in an `object`, and the `object` is added onto the `array` in `storage`. Then, I create buttons in the popup based off of the length of the `array`.

EDIT: `objectArr` is of type `number` and `groupObject` is of type `object`. Before I push `groupObject` onto `objectArr`, I can access `objectArr's length`, and I can still access `objectArr's length` after I push. However, when I actually update `objectArr`, `objectArr` becomes a `number`.

## background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(onInstall);

/* runs on installation of extension */
function onInstall()
{
    // objectArr will store the group objects
    var objectArr = new Array();
    chrome.storage.local.set({"objectArr": objectArr});
    // initializes groupCount to 0
    chrome.storage.local.set({"groupCount": 0});
}

function storeTabs(storeTabs)
{
    chrome.storage.local.get(["groupCount", "objectArr"], function(group)
    {
        // current count of groups
        var groupCount = group.groupCount;

        var promptUser = storeTabs;

        var groupObject = {};

        /* stores all of the tab's information into an object and then puts object into storage */
        chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function(tabs)
        {
            /* gets each tab's name and url from an array of tabs and stores them into arrays */
            var tabNamesArr = [];
            var tabUrlsArr = [];
            var tabCount = 0;

            for (; tabCount < tabs.length; tabCount++)
            {
                tabNamesArr[tabCount] = tabs[tabCount].title;
                tabUrlsArr[tabCount] = tabs[tabCount].url;
            }

            /* initialize object content */
            var groupName = "groupName" + groupCount;
            groupObject[groupName] = promptUser;

            var tabNames = "tabNames" + groupCount;
            groupObject[tabNames] = tabNamesArr;

            var tabUrls = "tabUrls" + groupCount;
            groupObject[tabUrls] = tabUrlsArr;

            console.log("before push, group.objectArr.length: " + group.objectArr.length);
            var objectArr = group.objectArr.push(groupObject);
            console.log("after push, group.objectArr.length: " + group.objectArr.length);
            console.log("typeof group.objectArr: " + typeof group.objectArr);
            console.log("typeof group.objectArr.push(groupObject): " + typeof objectArr);

            // updates storage with new objectArr with groupObject
            chrome.storage.local.set({"objectArr": objectArr});

            /* prints everything in storage */
            chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items) 
            {
                var allKeys = Object.keys(items);
                console.log("storage: " + allKeys);
            })

            /* prints objectArr and objectArr.length */
            chrome.storage.local.get("objectArr", function(group)
            {
                console.log("objectArr: " + group.objectArr);
                console.log("objectArr.length: " + group.objectArr.length);
            })

            // set-up for next group so last group isn't overwritten
            chrome.storage.local.set({"groupCount": (groupCount + 1)});
        })
    }
}
```

## popup.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
{
    var storeTabs = document.getElementById("storeTabs");
    storeTabs.addEventListener("keyup", function(enterKey)
    {
        if (enterKey.keyCode == 13)
        {
            // get text from text field
            var storeTabs = document.getElementById("storeTabs").value;

            chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().storeTabs(storeTabs);
        }
    })
}


displayButtons();

/* Display buttons for popup */
function displayButtons()
{
    chrome.storage.local.get("objectArr", function(group)
    {
        var objectArr = group.objectArr;

        console.log("objectArr: " + group.objectArr);
        console.log("objectArr.length: " + objectArr.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < objectArr.length; i++)
        {
            getStorage(i);
        }
    })
}
```

## background script console

```
before push, group.objectArr.length: 0
after push, group.objectArr.length: 1
typeof group.objectArr: object
typeof group.objectArr.push(groupObject): number
storage: groupCount,objectArr
objectArr: 1
objectArr.length: undefined
```

## popup script console

```
objectArr: 1
objectArr.length: undefined
```

Comment: what is `typeof objectArr`

Comment: Ahh its of type `number`. I also checked groupObject's type and its of type `object`. Am I storing the object into the array wrong?

Comment: I don't know, haven't read any of the code other where you console.log - it occurred to me that `objectArr` is not an array. The why of that is probably easy to debug now that you know it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is wrong.

```
        console.log("before push, group.objectArr.length: " + group.objectArr.length);
        // var objectArr = group.objectArr.push(groupObject); assinged 1...
        group.objectArr.push(groupObject);
        var objectArr = group.objectArr;
        console.log("after push, group.objectArr.length: " + group.objectArr.length);
        console.log("typeof group.objectArr: " + typeof group.objectArr);
        console.log("typeof group.objectArr.push(groupObject): " + typeof objectArr);
```

Comment: Yes that was it! Thank you!

Comment: How would you access an object's property that is in an array? Would it be `objectArr[0]["tabUrls" + 0]`?